# Am I going to be Fired?

Tags: termination

I was mad last month and I decided to take 2 weeks off.

They paid me anyway.

I had to take last friday off, and now there was a strange escallation (CEO was in CC stating I was absent for a sudden meeting while I was out for a short break).

I went to talk to HR, and then she spoke to CEO who had shown me he wasn't happy etc.

The CEO told me that I should resign or find a way to leave because I am not as responsible as they expect their workers to be.

Then, he asked the HR about my resignation and how many weeks notice, and she told him that "he didn't resign" or anything.

A litte after, HR comes to me and talks nice to me and tells me that I have to make efforts to comfort top management again.

-- He thought I had already turned in my resignation letter.

This CEO seems to be always missing information and relies much on gossip and social media.

At the end of the day, I was assigned a reporting/typing job instead of programming stuff.

Am I being tested or are they planning to get rid of me?

Comment: You took two weeks off without permission or notice? You just went and didn’t turn up for work for two weeks?

Comment: I had a medical certificate, stating I need to rest.

Comment: Please tag your nation and/or state

Comment: He thought you had already resigned because he told you to, I don't find that surprising at all.  Most people try hard to do what the CEO tells them to do.

Comment: He told her something like "what does his resigning letter say, the one he turned in"?

Comment: Where are you?  In most US states, 3 days unapproved absence is considered job abandonment, and you won't even be eligible for unemployment benefits.

Comment: "Am I being tested" - No. They can assign you the typing/reporting job indefinitely if they don't want to fire you but they want to limit damage. Probably they expect you will quit sooner or later.

Comment: So, to clarify, you were off sick for two weeks with a medical certificate?  The CEO obviously wants to sack you but isn't convinced he can make a legal case for firing you for misconduct, and doesn't want to lay you off and have to pay you severance.  Make looking for a new job your top priority, as they will find a way to get rid of you before too much longer.

Comment: I was re-assured and sacking is not in their agenda. My boss came to me and told me that I have to stay in this project for a month or two, until a new project on the way comes to the center. The reporting/typing job was canceled. The CEO came this morning and shook my hand with a smile. It was a misunderstanding I guess.

Comment: I took two weeks leave of absence as a manouver to get rid of this position and this strange situation a project manager was putting me in. I was living the case of "Managers Threatened By Their Talented and more Experienced Employees", and I had to stop it, and I resorted to this alternative.

Comment: This project manager was like "It's okay to be mediocre, let me pile on your work to the other hard working guy". I had shown much flexibility, but when I asked for two days off, I had more and more work at the end of the day so that the next day I come instead of taking it off. I think top management started to understand this.

Answer (score 10):

> **The CEO told me that I should resign** or find a way to leave because I am not as responsible as they expect their workers to be.

Seems pretty clear to me what they are planning...

You should probably start looking for a new job.

Comment: Although he thought I already resigned?

Comment: Not turning up to work for two weeks is basically throwing your job away. People don’t do that and expect to keep their jobs...

Comment: What are they waiting for, then?

Comment: @Bonaparte You didn't tell us where you live or whether you're at-will, but firing people is hard in some situations in some places. Asking you to resign is not firing you.

Comment: The meeting just happened, HR, during the second meeting, told me don't resign, kind of "he didn't mean it" ...

Comment: I am not in the US, by the way.

Comment: @Bonaparte , I would expect they're working to get rid of you. It may not be immediate, many larger companies have pretty lengthy procedures for actually firing someone, yet some others will just walk you out the door as soon as they want you gone. You haven't really noted where you're at, so your area's culture on this is unknown to us. I'll just say, though - I've seen employees get away with *months* of terminable behavior before being finally let go. I'd suggest looking for a new job immediately; they'll likely terminate you as soon as they feel comfortable and without liability.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like this isn't in the U.S., so your mileage may vary.

They want you to resign so that they don't have to pay any severance or unemployment insurance.  If you quit, you forfeit potential benefits.

Comment: There's no way of knowing why they want him to resign, and severance/unemployment insurance laws are highly dependent on OP's location, and may not even be a factor in the CEO's comment.